# OpenAI Authentication error: No API key provided for open ai api

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chatgpt-plugin

AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = ', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = '. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface.

I am running this on collab
the current code I am using

```
import os
import openai
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv()) # read local .env file

openai.api_key  = os.getenv('API-KEY')
def get_completion(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0, # this is the degree of randomness of the model's output
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"]
def collect_messages(_):
    prompt = inp.value_input
    inp.value = ''
    context.append({'role':'user', 'content':f"{prompt}"})
    response = get_completion_from_messages(context) 
    context.append({'role':'assistant', 'content':f"{response}"})
    panels.append(
        pn.Row('User:', pn.pane.Markdown(prompt, width=600)))
    panels.append(
        pn.Row('Assistant:', pn.pane.Markdown(response, width=600, style={'background-color': '#F6F6F6'})))
 
    return pn.Column(*panels)

//i get error when I run this piece of block
import panel as pn  # GUI
pn.extension()

panels = [] # collect display 

context = [ {'role':'system', 'content':"""
You are OrderBot, an automated service to collect orders for a pizza restaurant. \
You first greet the customer, then collects the order, \
and then asks if it's a pickup or delivery. \
You wait to collect the entire order, then summarize it and check for a final \
time if the customer wants to add anything else. \
If it's a delivery, you ask for an address. \
Finally you collect the payment.\
Make sure to clarify all options, extras and sizes to uniquely \
identify the item from the menu.\
You respond in a short, very conversational friendly style. \
The menu includes \
pepperoni pizza  12.95, 10.00, 7.00 \
cheese pizza   10.95, 9.25, 6.50 \
eggplant pizza   11.95, 9.75, 6.75 \
fries 4.50, 3.50 \
greek salad 7.25 \
Toppings: \
extra cheese 2.00, \
mushrooms 1.50 \
sausage 3.00 \
canadian bacon 3.50 \
AI sauce 1.50 \
peppers 1.00 \
Drinks: \
coke 3.00, 2.00, 1.00 \
sprite 3.00, 2.00, 1.00 \
bottled water 5.00 \
"""} ]  # accumulate messages


inp = pn.widgets.TextInput(value="Hi", placeholder='Enter text here…')
button_conversation = pn.widgets.Button(name="Chat!")

interactive_conversation = pn.bind(collect_messages, button_conversation)

dashboard = pn.Column(
    inp,
    pn.Row(button_conversation),
    pn.panel(interactive_conversation, loading_indicator=True, height=300),
)

dashboard
```

as it suggested to change 'openai.api_key = ' in the error box when I changed from `openai.api_key  = os.getenv('API-KEY')` to `openai.api_key = <API-KEY>` it gave syntax error

Comment: OPENAI_API_KEY or API-KEY? You seem surprised that *openai.api_key = <API-KEY>* gave a syntax error

Comment: In the last line, its not clear if you literally put `<API-KEY>` in your code, or if you're using that as a placeholder for your actual API Key so as to not share it.
  The authentication error sounds like you didn't actually put your key in your `.env` file or manually export it as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you're working in a Google Colab, I see.
Had similar issue in Colab, going from this code:

```
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = os.getenv("thisisadummyapikey123456789")

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
  messages=[
    {...
```

Which gave error:

```
AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>). If your API key is stored in a file, you can point the openai module at it with 'openai.api_key_path = <PATH>'. You can generate API keys in the OpenAI web interface. See https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys for details.
```

Since not needing an environment variable, it worked by removing the .getenv from the openapi boilerplate:

```
openai.api_key = "thisisadummyapikey123456789"
```

Can you try this first to make sure your authentication by itself is ok?

After that if still issues, please also document your environmental variable setup here, so we can look further.

Comment: This is the only valid solution.  Much better than `OpenAI.api_key`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
openai.api_key  = os.getenv('API-KEY')
```

Do this:

`openai.api_key = 'abcde12345789'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is absolutely weird but after setting the key as mentioned in the answer worked.